# Use regex to parse messy currency strings PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, currency

I have strings representing currencies from all over the world, I've stripped the currency symbols but I'm struggling with commas in the output.

```
sum(CASE
           WHEN (t.value ~ '^([0-9]+.?[0-9]*|.[0-9]+)$'::text) THEN (t.value)::numeric
           ELSE (0)::numeric
           END),
```

I get the following error with this:

```
invalid input syntax for type numeric: "750,000"
```

I can't make sense of the regex, everything here should parse only 0-9 and  escape '.', but there's a comma leaking through and I can't see where that could happen.

Comment: Have you tried to debug with RegExp debugger? ex. https://regex101.com/

Comment: To match a dot, it must be escaped. `.` matches any char.

Comment: If the comma is always the group separator, then just remove it: `replace(t.value, ',', '')::numeric`

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I should have said, I'm trying to up my knowledge on regex and wanted to see if I could it without using `replace`. Thanks @Wiktor, the problem I have with regex is that I get the principles but always fall short in the implementation, I'll see how I go.

Comment: Well, you have to get rid of the `,` before you can cast the value. There is no way around it. The only other alternative is to use `to_number()` with the correct format mask

Comment: I get it now, the regex is working to validate whether or not a string can be parsed, I then need to parse it, and so I do need the replace.